# Formatting and manipulating text input forms with php

Tags: php, html

I'm pretty new to PHP, sorry for the newb question :-)

I'm building a website and I want the client to be able to manipulate everything on it, including the text for pages such as FAQ, Terms and Conditions etc.

Basically there will be an admin page with a textarea input form, and the admin will upload/edit the content to a mysql database. Let's say I want the content to look like this :

Headline 1
Bla bla bla bla

Headline 2
Bla bla bla bla
.
.
.
. 
etc.

and then when it is uploaded / retrieved from mysql the format is kept.  don't really know what to use, is there an WYSIWYG editor, or php extension that will allow this? Or what is the best way in going about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own contentmanagement system (CMS).

Or to keep it the easy way, just try following some tutorials to develop your own weblog.

Then you will understand how to make something you want right now.

Good editor is FCKEditor!

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys! Can I do simple stuff with just php or do I need something like joomla! as well?

Comment: PHP is like the justice system in Holland, you can do whatever you want without getting punnished ;)! Joomla is a content management system and inapropiate for you i think at this time.

Answer (score 1):

tinyMCE is the thing you need if you're looking to make a CMS

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

Answer (score 1):

[FCKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: Thanks! Can I do simple stuff with just php or do I need something like joomla! as well?

Comment: You need only php. He integrates very simple. very flexible.